# Solve PDE: $f_{xx}+2f_{xy}+f_{yy}-2(f_x+f_y)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the genereal solution to the PDE
>
> $$f_{xx}+2f_{xy}+f_{yy}-2(f_x+f_y)=0,$$
>
> where $f(x,y)\in C^2$ by introducing the new variables $u=e^{x+y}, \
>  v=e^{x-y}.$ Hint: Note that $u_x=u_y, \ v_x=v, \ v_y=-v.$

I have that

$$
\begin{align}
f_{x}
&=f_uu_x+f_vv_x=f_uu+f_vv\tag1\\
f_{y}&=f_uu_y+f_vv_y=f_vu-f_vv\tag2\\
\end{align}
$$

Differentiating $(1)$ w.r.t $x$ again gives:

$$f_{xx}=u(f_{uu}\cdot u+f_{vv}\cdot v)+f_u\cdot u+\color{red}{v(f_{vu}\cdot u+f_{vv}\cdot v)}+f_v\cdot v= \tag3$$

$$=u^2f_{uu}+2uvf_{uv}+v^2f_{vv}+uf_u+vf_v.$$

**Question:** Why does $f_{vu}$ come before $f_{vv}$ in $(3)?$ Following the previous logic, should it not be $v(f_{vv}\cdot u + f_{vu} \cdot v)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\partial_x=u_x\partial_u+v_x\partial_v=u\partial_u+v\partial_v$ and similarly $\partial_y=u\partial_u-v\partial_v$, $\partial_x+\partial_y=2u\partial_u$. We have $$0=(\partial_x+\partial_y)(\partial_x+\partial_y-2)f=4u\partial_u (u\partial_u f-f)=4u^2\partial^2_u f.$$ Thus $f$ solves our original PDE iff $f$ is linear in $u$.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: @Parseval I think you've applied $v\partial_v$ to $u f_v$, which should be $vf_v$, and to $vf_u$, which should be $uf_u$.